# VBA - Compile Error, Expected: line number or label or statement or end of statement

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use Excel VBA to set up Task Reminders in Outlook, so I found this code from here:
http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/using-excel-vba-to-set-up-task-reminders-in-outlook/

```
Dim bWeStartedOutlook As Boolean

Function AddToTasks(strDate As String, strText As String, DaysOut As Integer) As Boolean
=AddToTasks(B2, M2 Time, 120)



' Adds a task reminder to Outlook Tasks a specific number of days before the date specified
' Returns TRUE if successful
' Will not trigger OMG because no protected properties are accessed
' by Jimmy Pena, http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com, 10/30/2008
'
' Usage:
' =AddToTasks("12/31/2008", "Something to remember", 30)
' or:
' =AddToTasks(A1, A2, A3)
' where A1 contains valid date, A2 contains task information, A3 contains number of days before A1 date to trigger task reminder
'
' can also be used in VBA :
'If AddToTasks("12/31/2008", "Christmas shopping", 30) Then
'  MsgBox "ok!"
'End If
 
Dim intDaysBack As Integer
Dim dteDate As Date
Dim olApp As Object ' Outlook.Application
Dim objTask As Object ' Outlook.TaskItem
 
' make sure all fields were filled in
If (Not IsDate(strDate)) Or (strText = "") Or (DaysOut <= 0) Then
  AddToTasks = False
  GoTo ExitProc
End If
 
' We want the task reminder a certain number of days BEFORE the due date
' ex: if DaysOut = 120, then we want the due date to be -120 before the date specified
' we need to pass -120 to the NextBusinessDay function, so to go from 120 to -120,
' we subtract double the number (240) from the number provided (120).
' 120 - (120 * 2); 120 - 240 = -120
 
intDaysBack = DaysOut - (DaysOut * 2)
 
dteDate = NextBusinessDay(CDate(strDate), intDaysBack)
 
On Error Resume Next
  Set olApp = GetOutlookApp
On Error GoTo 0
 
If Not olApp Is Nothing Then
  Set objTask = olApp.CreateItem(3)  ' task item
 
  With objTask
    .StartDate = dteDate
    .Subject = strText & ", due on: " & strDate
    .ReminderSet = True
    .Save
  End With
 
Else
  AddToTasks = False
  GoTo ExitProc
End If
 
' if we got this far, it must have worked
AddToTasks = True
 
ExitProc:
If bWeStartedOutlook Then
  olApp.Quit
End If
Set olApp = Nothing
Set objTask = Nothing
End Function
 
Function GetOutlookApp() As Object
 
On Error Resume Next
  Set GetOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set GetOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    bWeStartedOutlook = True
  End If
On Error GoTo 0
 
End Function
Sub Test()
```

My question is, if I have all the data in the spreadsheet, and I initiallize AddToTasks like so:
    =AddToTasks(A1, A2, 120)

Why does it come up with that error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `AddToTasks` from a separate `Subroutine`. (Right now you are trying to call it from inside itself.) So, create a separate `Subroutine` something like this:

```
Sub CallAddToTasksFunction

If AddToTasks("12/31/2008", "Something to remember", 30) = True Then
   Debug.Print "Task Added"
Else
   Debug.Print "Failed"
End If
End Sub
```

`AddToTasks` returns `True` or `False` depending on if it succeeded. You can see where that happens in a couple of spots in the function where the code is like:

```
AddToTasks = False (or True)
```

and you can see that things like dates that aren't really dates will cause it to fail.